# Robustly detect dash in PHP string

Tags: php, regex

I need a robust way to detect a dash in a string. The code below sometimes works and sometimes don't.

```
    $currenttitle = $item_name;
    $pattern = '/ [^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+| –/';
    $matches = array();
    $dummy = preg_match($pattern, $currenttitle, $matches);
    $posi = strpos($currenttitle, $matches[0]);
    $productname = substr($currenttitle, 0, $posi);
    $productcolor = substr($currenttitle, $posi+3);
    $dummy = preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/', $productcolor, $matchester);
    $productcolor = trim($matchester[0]);


    var_dump($productcolor);
```

In some cases $productcolor gives `STRING(22) "8211; STRIPE STONE"` instead of only "STRIPE STONE". It seems that sometimes the dash is encoded to `&#8211;`. How can I make this more robust ?

Comment: Or apply https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php first.

Comment: `&#8221` is the so-called "n-dash". There also exists an "mdash", code `&#8212;`. Edit: maybe worth to mention: both htmlentities have an hexadecimal notation as well: `&#x2013;` and `&#x2014;`

Comment: Use `\p{Pd}` to match any hyphen. When working with Unicode texts, use `/u` modifier with your regexps.

Comment: Note `\p{Pd}` does not match a soft hyphen, `\xAD`, you will need to include it if you need that, `[\p{Pd}\xAD]`

Comment: Thanks `[\p{Pd}\xAD]` works fine